# Singleton object scope, dealloc - iOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, static, singleton

I have some doubts about `singleton` object scope. I want to clear them.

We should call `removeObserver` for NSNotificationCenter method in every class `dealloc()` method which is observing any notification.

Do we need to do it for singleton class as well?

we use **`static`** keyword for singleton object reference and as per my knowledge static variable life-time is the program/app.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

I am asking for both swift and objective-c.

I know that we don't need to **unregister** **`NSNotification`** observer from iOS9 onwards.
Would It cause crash If I **unregister** notification observres in **iOS9+** as well

Thanks!

Comment: Add code to see what you did wrong. Show how you created singleton object and how you added observers to it.

Comment: Yes, `static` keeps the object alive for the life of the app (assuming it is `readonly` and can't be set to `nil` in the future and assuming you've written the class to prevent accidental instantiation of additional instances). Having said that, I'd still perform the necessary cleanup in `dealloc` regardless, in case I (or some future developer) ever decide later to convert it to a non-singleton pattern, adopting some more scalable or more easily tested pattern, such as dependency injection. Either way, I'd put comments in the code to make explicit whatever assumptions I've made.

Comment: In iOS 9+ you don't need to unregister obeservers in dealloc

Comment: “Would It cause crash If I unregister notification observers in iOS9+ as well” ... No, it wouldn’t.